# Exporting/importing specific column families of bigtable

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

My team is considering exporting/importing bigtable data, but just a subset of column families (not all) for technical issues.

These docs seem to suggest that export/import is possible only for the entire bigtable.

https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/exporting-sequence-files
https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/importing-sequence-files

We want to avoid exporting the entire bt due to its size (and we only need specific column families to be backed-up/restored).

Perhaps there is an easy solution to this that we are not aware of, so I thought I would ask here.

Another approach we thought of was to use Dataflow to scan specific column families, dump the data to GCS (by means of keeping a snapshot), and recover the data when it's needed. But if we don't need to use Dataflow, that will be a better solution for us.

Any help and suggestions will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can currently set a single column family via `-Dhbase.mapreduce.scan.column.family=<your_family>` on the command line.

We're currently working on improving our Import / Export process.  If you'd like, you can request an enhancement in our [github issues](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client/issues), and we should be able to get to it fairly quickly.  The following should be relatively easy to implement, but is not currently implemented:

```
-Dhbase.mapreduce.scan.column.families=<your families separated by commas>
```

Comment: I submitted a github issue: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client/issues/1140